# Should implementing methods have JavaDoc commentary if the interface they implement has JavaDoc commentary

Tags: java, javadoc

Assume I have an interface as follows.

```
public interface MyInterface{

 /**
 * This method prints hello
 */
  void sayHello();

  /**
  * This method prints goodbye
  */
  void sayGoodBye();
}
```

A concrete class implements these methods. Now do the methods in the concrete class also needs to define the javadocs on top of its method definition? I see some people just copying the same javadoc definition to the concrete class's implemented methods. I don't see this as a good practice because if we are to change the doc definition we need to change it in multiple places.

what is the standard practice for this?

Comment: In interface where you declare methods can have the overview of what the method does. In implementation, if required, you can have a step-by-step explanation in method to tell what the method exactly does. Ideally if you use proper coding standard its not required to give such a detailed explanation.

Comment: Are you meaning to say interface method javadocs should be brief?

Comment: yes, but also descriptive enough to make the reader understand what the API is suppose to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `{@inheritDoc}` to inherit the documentation of the interface and just add extra comments if you think they are significant and relevant extra info for the specific implementation.

**Only use @inheritDoc if you intend to add to the original superclass/interface documentation**. If you only want a copy, Javadoc will take care of that. It will see that the superclass documentation applies to the subclass's overridden method because the subclass provided no additional documentation.

> `{@inheritDoc}` - Inherits (copies) documentation from the "nearest" inheritable class or implementable interface into the current doc comment at this tag's location. This allows you to write more general comments higher up the inheritance tree, and to write around the copied text.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#@inheritDoc

Comment: You don't need to do that.  And there is little point doing that *unless* you want to add material that is specific to the implementation ... and have both the inherited and added material in the same text block.

Answer (score 3):

> Now do the methods in the concrete class also needs to define the javadocs on top of its method definition?

No. It's already specified. The concrete methods should do exactly what the interface Javadoc says and nothing else.

> I see some people just copying the same javadoc definition to the concrete class's implemented methods. I don't see this as a good practice because if we are to change the doc definition we need to change it in multiple places.

You are correct. They should not do this.

You should not use `@inheritDoc` either, except in the very rare case where the concrete method needs more description than is already in the interface Javadoc. Most of the time you should not provide any Javadoc at all, not even:

```
/**
 *
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

You *should* provide commentary for the concrete implementation if

- the commentary for the interface is so generic it does not adequately specify the concrete implementation
- the concrete implementation relaxes any preconditions of the interface
- the concrete implementation has stricter (narrower) post conditions than the interface.